# Как с Java 8 Stream конвертировать char[] в byte[]?

Tags: java, потоки-данных, типы-данных

В конечном счёте мне нужно из строки сделать массив байт. Как это сделать красиво? Ведь обычное приведение, если в цикле, было бы b[i] = (char) ch[i], но я хочу на этом примере понять как работают стримы.
Я пока смог сделать только массив интов, он пройдёт, но так добавилось лишнее расширение и потом будет сужение.

```
final int[] ints = str.chars().map(operand -> (byte) operand).toArray();
```

Строка у меня в ascii, так что 256 символов хватает.

Comment: Почему вам не подходит `str.getBytes()` ?

Comment: Stream API - это прикольная штука, которая **не** предназначена для замены вообще всех операций по работе с коллекциями. Зачастую проще, быстрее и лучше делать все альтернативными методами.

Comment: Друзья хватит занудствовать, человек же написал, что просто тренируется и хочется попробовать новый для себя api, пускай и на неоптимальных и бестолковых задачах.

Comment: @Nofate, я не знал про такую фичу. Очень удобно и решает мою конкретную задачу. Было бы это ответом, я бы отметил это как решение. Но вопрос оставлю как пример приведения элементов массива через стрим. PS: не пойму, как работает обращение по нику, собачку поставил, ник скопировал, но он не отображается как ссылка.

Comment: @Eugene он и не должен становиться ссылкой. Упоминания через собаку в комментариях попадают в нотификации упоминаемому участнику.

Answer (score 1):

У вас не получится сделать при помощи stream'ов массив `char`. В `java` стримы есть только для примитивный типов: int, long и double.
Можно добиться получения массива `Character`, но это уже, как вы понимаете, не будет массив примитивов:

```
Character[] array = "hello world".chars().mapToObj(s -> (char) s).toArray(Character[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str = " qadadsadsa";

    int[] ints = str.chars().toArray(); // есть легкий способ

    System.out.println(ints); // байты

   // по другим вопросам


    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(){{
            this.add("5");
            this.add("5");
            this.add("4");
            this.add("8");
            this.add("9");
            this.add("1");
            this.add("6");
    }};

    List<String> strings = list
            .stream()
            .filter(f -> f.equals("5")) // все, что равно 5
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // собрать результат в list

    ArrayList<M> list2 = new ArrayList<M>(){{
        this.add(new M(1,1));
        this.add(new M(2,2));
        this.add(new M(3,3));
        this.add(new M(4,4));
        this.add(new M(5,5));
        this.add(new M(6,6));
        this.add(new M(7,7));

    }};


    List<M> res = list2.stream()
            .filter(f -> f.b > 3) // только те результаты, где b > 3
            .limit(2) // ограничить до двух элементов (первые 2)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // собрать результат в list



    List<Integer> collect = res
            .stream()
            .map(m -> m.a) // брать только значения а
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // собрать результат в list


public class M {
    public int a, b;

    public M(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "M{" +
                "a=" + a +
                ", b=" + b +
                '}';
    }
}
```